# What is \003 special for?

Tags: special-characters

This special character is supposed to be able to kill kgdb：

```
echo -e "\003" > /dev/ttyS1
```

What's that character?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\003` is a Control-C, i.e., ^C, as in the character typically generated by the key sequence used to terminate a process from the terminal.

[reference](http://donsnotes.com/tech/charsets/ascii.html)

Answer (score 3):

That would be [end-of-text character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-text_character)

See the table from [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_and_C1_control_codes#C0_.28ASCII_and_derivatives.29)